# How to get the rotational speed around 2 axes by a given set of position vectors

Tags: qt, matlab, math, vector, 3d

I have a huge set of normalized position vectors.  The vector-set is recorded by a special measurement device, while the device is rotate around two axes. Every position vector is also a combination of gravitational values for X, Y, and Z at a defined time.  My assignment is to get the rotational speed of the both axes.

The coordinate system of the measurement device is rotated by circa 45° around the z-axis  in relation to the coordinate system of machine.

The z-axis of the measurement device parallel to the z-axis of the machine.
[image: coordinate systems]

I have tried to convert the carthesian coordinates to spherical coordinates. For this i used the Qt-Framework and MATLAB. As a result I got 2 angles and a radius. In my opinion the radius is not important. But the 2 angles don’t fit my problem, because I need the rotational speed of machine around the machine Z-axis and the X-axis. At this point it is important to know that the rotational speed is so slow that gravity-vector pointed always with 1g in to the ground. The X-,Y-, and Z-values of the  measurement device represents the orientation subject to the gravity-vector . For example if the Z-axis pointed to the Ground the value is nearly 1. And if the axis is parallel to the ground (also orthogonal to the gravity-vecot) the value is nearly zero.

If the machine only rotates around the Z-axis I can get the period of one rotation very easy. The plot of the Y-values and X-values subject to the time is a sine or cosine. So I can get period by searching for the zero point, the maxima or the minima.

rotation around the z-axis
[image: rotation around the machines z-axis]

But this solution fit only the 1axis-problem. If the machine rotates additional around the X-axis the measured X-, Y-, and Z-values are combinations of both rotations. I have no idea how I can fix my problem.

rotation around the machines z-axis and x-axis: the rotation starts after 55s!
[image: rotation around the machines z-axis and x-axis]

Another idea is the inverse kinematic but for this I need the dimensions of the machine and the exact point where the measurement device is mounted.

rotation around 1 axis
[image: rotation around 1 axis]

[Dataset rotation around 1 axis](http://hermes.et.hs-wismar.de/~bmt09020/DEV/1Axis.xlsx)

rotation around 2 axis
[image: rotation around 2 axis]

[Dataset rotation around 2 axes](http://hermes.et.hs-wismar.de/~bmt09020/DEV/2Axes.xlsx)

How can I start or go ahead?

I have tried to visualize the rotational process with this picture.
[image: rotational process]

Comment: You need to define your axes.  Do you have nested gimbals?  If so, what it their order going from the accelerometer out to the earth mount?  The first series looks like the accelerometer is rotating about a horizontal z-axis.  In the second, is it still turning about a body z gimbal, which is itself now rotating about a perpendicular horizontal earth-fixed axis?  Any rotation is ambiguous with respect to what convention it is represented in.  It could be roll, pitch, heading, or rotation about a single axis, expressed in body (accelerometer) coordinates, or in earth-fixed coordinates.

Comment: I have tried to visualize the process in the last picture of my Question.
If the accelerometers Z-axis pointing to the ground (the z-axis is parallel to the gravitation vector with the same direction) then the z-value is the direction diametrically opposed the value is -1.

Comment: Where are you trying to go with this system?  This is actually a wonderful little problem that would make a good homework assignment, term-project, or masters thesis in estimation engineering.  The sophistication of the solution will depend on which it is.  Also, do you want the attitude of the internal accelerometer assembly, or the rotation angles of the inner and outer gimbals?  Attitude is easier than gimbal angles.

Comment: Hi, yes it is a assignment in module/course of second master-term. It is also somethink like a term-project but it's not the only project this term i have 5 more. I think the easier solution of both is okay. But can the attitude of the internal accelerometer assembly fit my problem? I think i need the the rotation angles of the inner and outer gimbals dependent on the time of every dataset to get the rotational speed of the two rotaion axes.  My biggest problem is that i'm a programmer and not a good mathematician.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to put this in as a comment, but there is a length limit there.  So, some clarifying questions / intermediate conclusions:

Thanks for the figures!  So it looks from your 4th figure above, the one showing 2-axis x-y-z sine waves, and from your diagram of the machine, like you have three coordinate systems:  The first is the earth frame, call it x1,y1,z1, as you show it in "machine picture" diagram.  The second frame call it x2,y2,z2 rotates about both the x1 and the x2 axes (they remain parallel).  The third frame x3,y3,z3 is the one that rotates about the z2 (=z3) axis.  Your accelerometers are fixed in the x3,y3,z3 coordinate frame.

Your single-axis data set has z3=z2 aligned with earth z1, and spins about z, so that x3 and y3 spin around sampling gravity in quadrature sine waves.

In your second data set, the outer gimbal x1=x2 rotates at a constant rate, giving rise to the perfect sine wave on the z accelerometer, while the inner z3=z2 gimbal also spins perhaps at a constant rate, but now the accelerometers on x3 and y3 have their amplitudes modulated by multiplying by the cosine of the x1/x2 rotation angle.

Does all this sound right?

One other thing we always need to know when estimating velocity from position measurements is some kind of model or concept of how your system changes in time:  Can we assume some maximum angular acceleration?  Or can we assume that once the rotation(s) come up to speed, that they are constant?  That will become especially important in trying to stitch the z2/z3 gimbal angle over the times when the x1/x2 angle passes through +/-pi/2 radians, where the z2/z3 angle becomes momentarily unobservable because the x and y accelerometers are orthogonal to the gravity vector and will just show noise.  It will also help us to decide if the x1/x2 gimbal went up to pi/2 and back down again, or kept turning in the same direction to > pi/2, because both motions look the same on the z accelerometer, and the z2/z3 angle is unobservable there.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:

```
Use two-argument arctangent.
The roll angle is atan2(ay, ax).
The pitch angle is atan2(az, sqrt(ax*ax + ay*ay)).
Then time-difference these to get angle rates.
```

This oversimplified solution has a number of problems, but it's a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the key you need is this:  You must transform the x and y accelerations from measurement coordinates to machine coordinates before estimating the pitch about the machine x axis.  This requires you to first know the roll angle (about the machine z axis).  In matlab sytax,

```
[x_machine; y_machine] = [cos(roll) -sin(roll); sin(roll) cos(roll)] * [x_meas; y_meas].
z_machine = z_meas, always.
```

Given x,y,z in machine coordinates, you can directly estimate the pitch angle and rate about the machine x axis:

```
pitch = atan2(z_machine, -y_machine)  (right hand rule about the machine x axis; positive acceleration pointing down); 
pitch_rate = -asin((xyz_i cross xyz_i-1)_x) / dt_i,
```

where in English, the rate is computed from the arcsine of the x_machine component of the cross product of the latest machine coordinate acceleration vector with the previous one, divided by the time between them (1/8 of a second in your case).
The same approach works for estimating roll and roll rate (about the machine z axis):

```
roll = atan2(-x_meas, -y_meas) * cos(pitch) / abs(cos(pitch));  
roll_rate = -asin((xyz_meas_i cross xyz_meas_i-1)_z) * cos(pitch) / abs(cos(pitch)) / dt_i.
```

It is a chicken-and-egg problem, where you need to know the pitch and roll to estimate pitch and roll and their rates.  So you need to start off with a good guess of the correct pitch and roll angles (to within 15 degrees or so should be fine).
All of the measurements are noisy, so the estimates will be also.  The rate estimates especially so.  So you will want to filter the estimates in time.  Propagate your pitch and roll angle estimates in time using your filtered angle rate estimates.
Also, your roll angle and rate estimates become pure noise as pitch is near +/-pi/2, so you should probably weight down the inputs to the roll filters by something like cos^2(pitch).